# Testing Spring with MockMvc

Tags: java, spring

please could help to me with Spring testing with MockMvc.

I have Controller(I deleted path code of metod)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/read/object-attributes")
public class GroupAttributeReadController {

@Autowired
private GroupAttributeService groupAttributeService;
@RequestMapping(value = "/import", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
GroupAttributeBufferListResponse findAll(@RequestParam(value = "pageNum", required = true) int pageNum,
                                     @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = true) int pageSize,
                                     @RequestParam(value = "order", required = false) String order,
                                     @RequestParam(value = "orderDir", required = false) String orderDir,
                                     @RequestParam(value = "loadSession") Long loadSession,
                                     @RequestParam( value = "showCorrect", defaultValue = "0") Integer showCorrect,
                                     @RequestParam(value="naviUser") String user,
                                     @RequestParam Map<String, String > params,
                                     HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) {

}
```

And my test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllersTest {
@Autowired
WebApplicationContext wac;

MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    DefaultMockMvcBuilder builder = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac);
    this.mockMvc = builder.build();
}

@Test
public void testController() throws Exception {
    ResultMatcher ok = MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk();

    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/read/object-attributes/import?pageNum=2&pageSize=5&order=test&orderDir=DESC&loadSession=1&showCorrect=0&naviUser=user&FILTER_Test=Test");
    this.mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(ok);
    }
}
```

But I'm not understand why response 404. Maybe I something forget? Maybe need config-file, I dont know :(

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
<Click to see difference>


at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:665)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Does the resource or the entry that you're trying to retrieve exists? First try to have the data by performing a `POST` and then do a `findAll(...)` on it.

Comment: Before `andExcpect(...)`, you can add `.andDo(print())`. This will provide you details of why it's failing. `print()` is from `MockMvcResultHandlers` class. Try this and tell us the error you get.

Comment: MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /read/object-attributes/download
       Parameters = {loadSession=[1], showCorrect=[0], FILTER_Test=[Test], naviUser=[user]}
          Headers = {}
Handler:
             Type = null
Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null
Resolved Exception:
             Type = null
ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null
FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

Comment: MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

Comment: The URI is `/read/object-attributes/download` instead of `/read/object-attributes/import`. That's weird. And it seems that some parameters are missing.

Comment: MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /read/object-attributes/import
       Parameters = {pageNum=[2], pageSize=[5], order=[test], orderDir=[DESC], loadSession=[1], showCorrect=[0], naviUser=[user], FILTER_Test=[Test]}
          Headers = {}

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake

Comment: Handler: Type = null. I think that because maybe need same config-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include `@ContextConfiguration` as well - here is a snippet from [`@WebAppConfiguration` documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/web/WebAppConfiguration.html):

> Note that `@WebAppConfiguration` must be used in conjunction with
>    `@ContextConfiguration`, either within a single test class or within a test class hierarchy.

So your test class should look something like that:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration( classes = AppConfig.class, WebConfig.class )
public class ControllersTest {
   (...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the required params.

Example:

`@Test
    public void testAddInformation() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/sample").param("name", "provideName").param("address", "provideAddress")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    };`

Comment: even if I have get request?

Comment: That is sample code. Implement it accordingly like if you have get put get..if post put post. Simple!

Comment: MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/read/object-attributes/import")
                .param("pageNum", "2")
                .param("pageSize", "5")
                .param("order", "test")
                .param("orderDir", "DESC")
                .param("loadSession", "1")
                .param("showCorrect", "0")
                .param("naviUser", "user")
                .param("FILTER_Test", "Test");

Comment: ResultMatcher ok = MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk();

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/read/object-attributes/import")
                .param("pageNum", "2")
                .param("pageSize", "5")
                .param("order", "test")
                .param("orderDir", "DESC")
                .param("loadSession", "1")
                .param("showCorrect", "0")
                .param("naviUser", "user")
                .param("FILTER_Test", "Test");
        this.mockMvc.perform(request)
                .andExpect(ok);

Comment: Can you try once like I did. Exactly in the same way and let me know the outcome